# Creating this pattern in python

Tags: python

Required to write a program to print out a square with given height and pattern as indicated below. (This is a square of 2x2 alternating blocks with the “=” pattern always in the top-left corner)

Input:

```
Enter the height:
6
```

Output:

```
==XX==

==XX==

XX==XX

XX==XX

==XX==

==XX==
```

Code:

```
x = eval(input("Enter the height: "))
j=0
i=0
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(x):
        if(i==0 or i==1):
            if(j == 0 or j == 1):
                print("=",end="")
            elif(j == 2 or  j== 3):
                print("X",end="")
                j=j+1
            elif(j==4):
                j=0

    if(i == 2 or i == 3):
        if(j == 0 or j == 1):
            print("X",end="")
        elif(j == 2 or j == 3):
            print("=",end="")
if(i==4):
    i=0
i=i+1
print()
```

only produces:

```
==XX

==XX

XX==

XX==
```

Comment: what's design pattern has to do with this? did you tried debugging? can you add python as tag and remove design patterns.

Comment: Try correct indentation......

Comment: Acutally, the output I get with your code and `6` is `==XX==XX` all in one line.

Comment: I don't understand, do you always want two lines in the middle?

Comment: To be honest: your code is a mess. You have statements out of the for loop that I think should be inside the loop, and you are changing the loop variable within the loop, which is always a bad idea. Why don't you try it with modulo (%)?

Comment: Please, don't use `eval` for that... :/. You can simply use `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Test for a valid input (it must be even number).

Calculate the number of groups (pairs) of rows and groups (pairs) of characters in each row (that's the input divided by 2).

Make a loop for a desired number of groups of rows.

Inside it make a loop for two rows.

Inside it make loop for a desired number of groups of signs.

Inside it make a loop for a desired number (2) of chars in the group.

Print a sign, which is either '=' if a parity of the number of a current rows' group is the same as a parity of the number of a current chars' group, 'X' otherwise.

At the end of each row (after the loop of chars group) print end of line.

Done.

Comment: the pattern always alternates between the ==XX
                                                                    ==XX
and it has to be a square

Comment: 'Square' means nothing unless you guarantee your output device has the character width and the line height equal. It's safer to talk about equal counts of characters in a group and rows (lines of text) in a group.

Answer (score 0):

You should use modulo when you do stuff with that kind of pattern.
In your code you only process the cases where i<4, your identation seems a bit random.

I think this will do what you want:

```
x = input("Enter the height: ")
output = ""
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(x):
        if (((i/2)%2 == 0 and ((j/2)%2) != 0) or ((i/2)%2 != 0 and ((j/2)%2) == 0)):
            output += "X"
        else:
            output += "="
        if (j%x == x-1):
            output += "\n"
print(output)
```